# Cannot assign value of type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status??' to type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status?'

Tags: swift, storekit

I'm trying to implement StoreKit in my project, specifically, the auto-renewable subscriptions, using [Apple's implementing StoreSit2 example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api).

I refactored Apple's project to only include a yearly subscription based on what I need for my app. I uploaded [the refactored project on Github](https://github.com/ramiammoun/storekitdemo). I did everything exactly as the project is setup, however, I get this error in the files: Store and StatusInfoView at the following line:
In "Store" line 214:

```
subscriptionGroupStatus = try? await subscriptions.first?.subscription?.status.first?.state
```

Error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalState??'
> to type 'RenewalState?' (aka
> 'Optional<Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalState>')

In "StatusInfoView" line 134:

```
 subscriptionStatus = try? await product.subscription?.status.last
```

Error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status??' to
> type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status?'

￼
**￼
The project on Github Does not produce error It shows after I copy paste the files to my Xcode project.**

I can't figure out how to fix value assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  @MainActor
    func updateCustomerProductStatus() async {
        var purchasedSubscriptions: [Product] = []

        //Iterate through all of the user's purchased products.
        for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
            do {
                //Check whether the transaction is verified. If it isn’t, catch `failedVerification` error.
                let transaction = try checkVerified(result)

                //Check the `productType` of the transaction and get the corresponding product from the store.
                switch transaction.productType {

                case .autoRenewable:
                    if let subscription = subscriptions.first(where: { $0.id == transaction.productID }) {
                        purchasedSubscriptions.append(subscription)
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            } catch {
                print()
            }
        }



        //Update the store information with auto-renewable subscription products.
        self.purchasedSubscriptions = purchasedSubscriptions

        //Check the `subscriptionGroupStatus` to learn the auto-renewable subscription state to determine whether the customer
        //is new (never subscribed), active, or inactive (expired subscription). This app has only one subscription
        //group, so products in the subscriptions array all belong to the same group. The statuses that
        //`product.subscription.status` returns apply to the entire subscription group.
        //let storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: productIdToEmoji.keys)

        subscriptionGroupStatus = try? await subscriptions.first?.subscription?.status.first?.state
    }


struct StatusInfoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @StateObject static var store = Store()
    @State static var subscription: Product?
    @State static var subscriptionStatus: Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status?
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            if let subscription, let subscriptionStatus {
                StatusInfoView(product: subscription, status: subscriptionStatus)
                    .environmentObject(store)
            }
        }
        .task {
            guard let product = store.purchasedSubscriptions.first else {
                return
            }
            subscription = product
            subscriptionStatus = try? await product.subscription?.status.last
        }
    }
```

Comment: Haven't we been through this? You asked this before, you didn't show then the code in which the error occurs, and you're not showing it now either.

Comment: This is a repeat of your now deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815671/cannot-assign-value-of-type-product-subscriptioninfo-status-to-type-product and you're just saying the same stuff as before. That's called "thrashing the site". Don't to it. The question was closed for a reason, and you were told the reason. Go back to that question and _read the comments_ telling you how to improve your question and _do_ what they are advising you to do.

Comment: And do not ask a new question _and_ try to reopen exactly the same question from before.

Comment: I added the entire project on Github, the previous question would not reopen even though I edited it to add the code on Github. The refactored project does not throw the error, it only does this only when I move it to my actual project

Comment: I really need this fixed, been trying for a week so far

Comment: You need to edit your question to include, as text, a minimal example of code that replicates your issue. When you do add the relevant code, please do not quote it by adding a `>` before every line. That makes it really difficult for anyone to copy and paste the code.

Comment: I added the code section here, thank you

Comment: You need to add more code. What you posted so far is missing too much. You need to post the bare minimum that can be copied and pasted such that the only error is the one you are asking about. Add all needed classes and properties but remove anything that isn't needed to reproduce your specific issue.

Comment: Don't ignore the error. Handle it. It seems that the issue is that you are trying to assign a double optional. I guess if you just handle the error it will probably result in a single optional result. try `do { subscriptionStatus = try await product.subscription?.status.last } catch { print(error) }`

Comment: The error was coming from a discrepancy in the swift version of the projects. Once I updated my project to Swift 5 the error disappeared. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The project from Apple was written in Swift 5. When I refactored the code and moved it to my project, which was written in Swift 4, it threw that syntax error at.
I updated my project to Swift 5 and the error was gone.
[image]